# TypeError: Object of type 'ObjectId' is not JSON serializable using Flask and MongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, flask

I want a dictionary to be inserted into a mongo db and to be returned.

I have found a couple of questions for this Error but all are related to READING queries. Since I am just inserting and do not need to parse any output I do not understand this behavior at all.

The main difference in the behavior comes with commenting in/out this line:

```
db_s41.links.insert_one(new_link_doc)
```

With the **line commented out**, the return of the object works properly. Obviously the document is not inserted.

With the **line not commented out**, the return does not work, the error gets thrown but still but still the documents is properly inserted into the db.

I am using the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

client = MongoClient(
    os.environ['DOCKER_FLASK_MONGODB_DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR'],
    27017
)

# Set db object
db_s41 = client.s41

@app.route('/new_link2')
def generate_link(berater="muster_berater", kunde='muster_kunde'):
   
    new_link_doc = {
        'link': 'test',
        'required_documents': [],
        'date_link_generated': 'test',
        'timestamp_link_generated': 'test',
        'berater_link_generated': 'test'
    }

    # insert into database 's41', collection 'links'
    db_s41.links.insert_one(new_link_doc)

    return new_link_doc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

I am using the following versions:

Docker version 20.10.1, build 831ebea
Mongo 4.4.2
Python 3.6.6
click        7.1.2
Flask        1.1.2
itsdangerous 1.1.0
Jinja2       2.11.2
MarkupSafe   1.1.1
pip          10.0.1
pymongo      3.11.2
setuptools   39.2.0
Werkzeug     1.0.1
wheel        0.31.1

I am truly grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting a document into MongoDB, if you don't specify an `_id` field, the pymongo drivers will add an `_id` field of type `ObjectId` to the document, before inserting into the database.

See https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#writes-and-ids

Flask is then trying to JSON serialise the field which it doesn't know how to do; hence the error.

A simple fix could be to just `pop` the `_id` before returning it; e.g.

```
# insert into database 's41', collection 'links'
db_s41.links.insert_one(new_link_doc)
new_link_doc.pop('_id')

return new_link_doc
```